# Comparing data in two text fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365, infopath-rules

I have two text boxes which compares the value in one text box with other. Assume `Text Box 1` has value as 1234 and `Text Box 2` has value 12345,123,12346.

Now I will be graying out the text box 1 by applying rule as `If Text Box 2 contains Text Box 1` then do conditional formatting of graying out. In this scenario Textbox 2 doesn't contain the value of Text Box 1 how ever the condition turns out to be true and then greys out. Its takes 123 which is present in text box 2 and as it finds relative match with 123(neglecting 4) it is returning true.

Text Box 2 value is obtained by concatenating several text box values with commas. I want to perform exact match and grey out if it contains. Is there a way I can grey out the text box 1 by comparing the value in text box 2 before and after comma of each value in textbox.

Here is what I am trying to avoid
[image]
[image]

As we see I entered 1234 in `Text Box 1` in fact this value is not present in `Text Box 2` however it stills grey out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following expression

[image]

```
contains(concat(my:field2, ","), concat(my:field1, ","))
```

I have tested following use cases

1. Field2 = "1,12,123,1234"

   - Field = "1"
   - Field = "12"
   - Field = "123"
   - Field = "1234"

Comment: Hashim, I have one question since I already have the concatenated string stored in textbox2. I was trying to put something like this in expression --> contains(my:field2) but its not working. Reason I am asking is I have around 80 controls which means I need to put This expression of concatenation in all of the controls.

Comment: There is no concept of global rules. You need to apply rules on individual text box controls.